# How to select the five greatest number mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

How to select the first five high number from my table
for example: bid_table > 10 customers enter bid, and the query need to give only the five high bid from this 10 customers

thanks
Yaniv

Comment: order by id DESC limit 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM bid_table ORDER BY bid DESC LIMIT 5;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT bid FROM bid_table
ORDER BY bid DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

The limit clause gives you just five results. The order by and desc parts give the results from highest to lowest.